# Can't get all data from Pivot Table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to work with a pivot table but I can't get all the data that I need. 
I have three DB tables:

```
1.ingredients
2.recipes
3.ingredients_in_recipe (Pivot table)
```

1.The ingredients table contains two ingredients:

```
--------------------
-- id | name      --
-- 1  | Potatoes  --
-- 2  | Onions    --
--------------------
```

2.The recipes table contains three recipes:

```
---------------------------------------------
-- id | name                               --
-- 1  | Recipe with potatoes               --
-- 2  | Recipe with onions                 --
-- 3  | Recipe with potatoes and onions    --
---------------
```

3.The ingredients_in_recipe table:

```
---------------------------------------
-- id | recipe_id| ingredient_id     --
-- 1  |    1     |      1            --
-- 2  |    2     |      2            --
-- 3  |    3     |      1            --
-- 4  |    3     |      2            --
---------------------------------------
```

Ingredient Model:

```php
   public function recipes() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Recipe', 'ingredient_recipe');
   }
```

Ingredient Controller:

```php
    public function read(Request $request)
    {
        //we search one or more id of ingredients (1=Potatoes, 2=Onions)
        $ingredients = Ingredient::findOrFail([1,2]);
        $recipes = [];
        foreach($ingredients as $ingredient) {
                $recipes = $ingredient->recipes()->get();
        }
      return view('home')->with('recipes', $recipes);
    }
```

View:

```php
    @foreach ($recipes as $recipe)
        {{$recipe->name}}
    @endforeach
```

I expected to get all the recipes from the query but actually I get only two recipes (recipe with onions (id:2) and recipe with potatoes and onions (id:3).

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, the following line is causing the problem:

```php
$recipes = $ingredient->recipes()->get();
```

It is only saving the recipes for the last ingredient.

I suggest you replace the contents of your `read` method it with this one:

```php
$ingredients = Ingredient::with('recipes')->findOrFail([1,2]);
$recipes = collect([]);
foreach($ingredients as $ingredient) {
    $recipes = $recipes->merge($ingredient->recipes);
}
return view('home')->with('recipes', $recipes);
```

Answer (score 0):

try below.

Ingredient Controller:

```
public function read(Request $request)
{
    $ingredients = Ingredient::with('recipes')->findOrFail([1,2]);
    $recipes = [];
    foreach($ingredients as $ingredient) {
            $recipes[] = $ingredient->recipes;
    }
  return view('home')->with('recipes', $recipes);
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained what OP did wrong and why this fixes it, instead of just dropping a block of code.